# Devexpress pivotgirid customization form for fields

Tags: forms, devexpress, customization

I have a button on ribbon control.When I click it I open a customization form which shows pivotgrid's fields and I drag items from customization form to the pivot grid but when I close and reclick the button to open the customization form the draged fields are not shown in the pivot.I have to reselect the fields to show on the pivot.

How can I avoid this?

Below code is for button click event.

```
private void barButtonItem10_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    pivotGridControl1.RetrieveFields(PivotArea.FilterArea, false);
    pivotGridControl1.FieldsCustomization();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`PivotGridControl.RetrieveFields`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraPivotGridPivotGridControl_RetrieveFieldstopic(w5D4CA)) method with your parameters are hiding all fields. If you remove this method from your code, then you will avoid your situation.

```
private void barButtonItem10_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    pivotGridControl1.FieldsCustomization();
}
```

Comment: thank to for your response.I have to use PivotGridControl.RetrieveFields method and pass parameter false other way fields are not shown in customization form.I solved the problem thanks. @nempoBu4